# Second external monitor does not turn on but is connected

Tags: debian, display, multi-monitor, monitors

I'm running debian 12 on a thinkpad T14s and have an issue with a second external monitor. I have both monitors connected to the thinkpad universal usb-c docking station and my laptop plugged into that.

Running xrandr confirms both monitors are connected but only my primary monitor is on and displaying anything. My secondary monitor is not activated and even if I manually turn it on there is no display.

However, unplugging my secondary monitor from the docking station and connecting it directly to my laptop lets me use both monitors.

xrandr output:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*XWAYLAND20 1920/600x1080/340+1080+0  XWAYLAND20
 1: +XWAYLAND22 1080/600x1920/340+0+0  XWAYLAND22

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 3000 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND20 connected primary 1920x1080+1080+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1920x1080    143.88*+
   1440x1080    143.80  
   1400x1050    143.89  
   1280x1024    143.79  
   1280x960     143.86  
   1152x864     143.92  
   1024x768     143.87  
   800x600      143.83  
   640x480      143.85  
   320x240      142.05  
   1680x1050    143.88  
   1440x900     143.86  
   1280x800     143.84  
   720x480      143.85  
   640x400      143.37  
   320x200      141.40  
   1600x900     143.93  
   1368x768     143.77  
   1280x720     143.67  
   1024x576     143.91  
   864x486      143.63  
   720x400      143.88  
   640x350      143.57  
XWAYLAND22 connected 1080x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   1920x1080    143.88*+
   1440x1080    143.80  
   1400x1050    143.89  
   1280x1024    143.79  
   1280x960     143.86  
   1152x864     143.92  
   1024x768     143.87  
   800x600      143.83  
   640x480      143.85  
   320x240      142.05  
   1680x1050    143.88  
   1440x900     143.86  
   1280x800     143.84  
   720x480      143.85  
   640x400      143.37  
   320x200      141.40  
   1600x900     143.93  
   1368x768     143.77  
   1280x720     143.67  
   1024x576     143.91  
   864x486      143.63  
   720x400      143.88  
   640x350      143.57
```